# Trying to call a certain function each time

Tags: c++, multithreading

Okay, so I've an assignment with threads.I'm suppose to change the current running threads each period of time, let's say a second. First of all I've created a Thread class:

```
 typedef unsigned long address_t;
 #define JB_SP 6
 #define JB_PC 7
#define STACK_SIZE (4096)

using namespace std;

class Thread{
public:
enum State{
    BLOCKED,
    READY,
    RUNNING
};
Thread(int tid, void(*f)(void), int stack_size) :
        tid(tid), stack_size(stack_size){
    address_t sp, pc;
    sp = (address_t)stack + STACK_SIZE - sizeof(address_t);
    pc = (address_t)f;
    sigsetjmp(env, 1);
    (env->__jmpbuf)[JB_SP] = translate_address(sp);
    (env->__jmpbuf)[JB_PC] = translate_address(pc);
    sigemptyset(&env->__saved_mask);
    state = READY;
    quantums = 0;
}
Thread (){}

address_t translate_address(address_t addr)
{
    address_t ret;
    asm volatile("xor    %%fs:0x30,%0\n"
            "rol    $0x11,%0\n"
    : "=g" (ret)
    : "0" (addr));
    return ret;
}
State get_state() const
{
    return state;
}
void set_state(State state1)
{
    state = state1;
}
int get_id() const
{
    return tid;
}
pthread_t& get_thread()
{
    return thread;
}

sigjmp_buf& get_env()
{
    return env;
}

void raise_quantums()
{
    quantums ++;
}

int get_quantums()
{
    return quantums;
}
int add_to_sync(int tid)
{
    sync.push_back(tid);
}
bool appear_in_sync_list(int tid)
{
    return (find(sync.begin(), sync.end(), tid) != sync.end());
}
private:
vector<int> sync;
int quantums;
State state;
char stack[STACK_SIZE];
sigjmp_buf env;
pthread_t thread;
int tid;
int stack_size;


};
```

I've this function which changes threads:

```
void running_thread(int sigNum)
{

sigset_t set;
sigemptyset(&set);
sigaddset(&set, SIGINT);
sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, &set, NULL);
total_quantum ++;
if (currentThread.get_state() == Thread::RUNNING)
{
    Thread& t = ready_threads.back();
    ready_threads.pop_back();
    currentThread.set_state(Thread::READY);
    ready_threads.push_back(currentThread);
    sigsetjmp(currentThread.get_env(), 1);
    currentThread = t;
    t.raise_quantums();
    siglongjmp(currentThread.get_env(), 1);
}
if (currentThread.get_state() == Thread::BLOCKED)
{
    Thread &t = ready_threads.back();
    ready_threads.pop_back();
    currentThread.set_state(Thread::BLOCKED);
    blocked_threads.push_back(currentThread);
    sigsetjmp(currentThread.get_env(), 1);
    currentThread = t;
    t.raise_quantums();
    siglongjmp(currentThread.get_env(), 1);

}
sigemptyset(&set);
sigaddset(&set, SIGINT);
sigprocmask(SIG_UNBLOCK, &set, NULL);
}
```

It actually doesn't matter what it do, my problem is that it isn't even called.

My program first call this function:

```
int clock_set()
{
int seconds = quantum / SECOND;
int usecs = quantum - seconds*SECOND;
timer.it_value.tv_sec = seconds;
timer.it_value.tv_usec = usecs;
timer.it_interval.tv_sec = seconds;
timer.it_interval.tv_usec = usecs;
struct sigaction sa;
sa.sa_handler = &running_thread;
if (sigaction(SIGVTALRM, &sa,NULL) < 0) {
    cerr << "system error: sigaction error.";
    return FAILURE;
}

// Start a virtual timer. It counts down whenever this process is executing.
if (setitimer (ITIMER_VIRTUAL, &timer, NULL)) {
    cerr << "system error: setitimer error.";
    return FAILURE;
}
return SUCCESS;
}
```

Basically I was trying to make running_thread get activate each second, so I Was using sigaction and sa_handler.

This is my main function:

```
int main()
{
uthread_init(1000000) // Initiliaze variable 'quantum' to be a second, this function also calls clock_set
uthread_spawn(&g); // Creating a thread object with function g inserting it to ready_threads vector and to threads vector
uthread_spawn(&f); // creating a thread object with function f inserting it to ready_threads vector and to threads vector



}
```

The vector "ready_threads" has 2 threads in it.
Why doesn't it call running_thread?

Comment: What is `Thread`? There's no such class in the C++ library. Also irrespective of whatever strange thread library this is, it's reasonaly to ass-ume that something called `currentThread` would end up referring to whatever execution thread this is. And if so, how exactly do you expect that `currentThread.get_state()` would tell you anything other than the fact that the current thread is running. Otherwise, it would not've been able to call `get_state()`, after all.

Comment: Hey Sam, thanks for commenting. Thread is a class that I've created, I do believe however it is irrelevant. I'm looking to understand how can I call "running_thread" each second, nonetheless what running_thread actually does. (I could fix it later..). I'm just looking to call it every second

Comment: If it is irrelavent, then why did you put it here? Can you please provide a [mcve]?

Comment: @tobi303 You know what tobi, you are right. I've deleted the contents of the running_thread function and replaced it by a simple cout<<h. This is in order to get an answer to my one true question, how do I get running_thread to get called every second ?

Comment: You do this by including a [mcve] in your question, instead of isolated code snippets. A complete, simple, short, test program that attempts to implement this the way you're trying to do, that anyone can compile, and test, for themselves.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik as you wish, I've edited.

Comment: thats still not an [mcve]. Dont get me wrong, just trying to help. There arent any `#includes` for example. If you want to know how to get a thread running each second, then write a small example that does that but nothing else. I am newbie to threads, but my guess is that you dont need more than 15 lines of code to try this out. If it doesnt work, then fix this 15 lines, before you write hundreds more. If you cant fix it at least you will have a nice mcve that demonstrates the problem such that others can reproduce it :)

Comment: What he said. A [mcve] doesn't mean "dump all your code into the question".